# Proper way to share sqlachemy session and egine in context of gevent

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, gevent

My code tried to create an engine first:

```
def createEngine(connectionstring):
    engine = create_engine(connectionstring, 
        #pool_size = DEFAULT_POOL_SIZE, 
        #max_overflow = DEFAULT_MAX_OVERFLOW, 
        echo = False)
    return engine
```

Then get a session from the engine:

```
@contextmanager
def getOrmSession(engine):
    try:
        Session.configure(bind=engine)
        session = Session()
        yield session
    finally:
        pass
```

The client code is as follows:

```
def composeItems(keyword, itemList):
    with getOrmSession(engine) as session:    
        for i in itemList:
            item = QueryItem(query=keyword, 
                        ......
                        active = 0)
            session.add(item)
        session.commit()
```

Then when i call composeItems within gevent spawn. Obviously, mysql deadlocks. What had happened? What is wrong with the above usage?

Answer (score 2):

Find the answer by myself.

I need to patch threading when import gevent. So scoped_session will be able to use greenlet's threading local. change the patching and everhything works fine now.